# Troubleshooting: cURL timeouts, Java app doesn't

Tags: networking, curl, wget

I'm trying to use curl against a remote server to access a REST API (and right now, just the welcome page...)
Currently, I have a Java application that can send REST request on this server.

But if I use curl (or wget), I get a timeout.

I believe the fact that a Java app can connect but not cURL would narrow down the problem a little but more.
Still, I know there are many many possibilities; I'm just looking for a way to troubleshoot the reason I'm having a timeout (so I can use cURL).

PS: It's https, on the same network, there is a certificate I tried using but it doesn't change anything.

Edit: With --verbose" or "--trace -" I just get :

> == Info: About to connect() to myserver.com port 443 (#0)
>
> == Info:   Trying xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx...

Comment: The `--verbose` and `--trace` options can show you what is happening behind the scenes when you use `curl`. You might also want to check with the `--insecure` flag to see if it narrows down to a TLS problem.

Comment: I wonder if that's a connectivity problem. From the same system, can you try `nc -v myserver.com 443` or `telnet myserver.com 443` and see if you're able to connect?

Comment: Unfortunately they are not installed for the moment, I'll try to install them and comme back with the results. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I though, it was something pretty simple: the application was configured to use a proxy, and cURL was not (even though both were using the same destination IP).